# Ember CLI and LinkedIn API

Tags: authentication, ember-cli

Has anyone been able to create a working Ember CLI app that can successfully make requests to the LinkedIn API?

I've been struggling with various cli addons without and luck and then finally realized that the LinkedIn API doesn't allow for cross-domain ajax requests / CORS. So I believe ember-simple-auth won't be able to work with LinkedIn.

Comment: I haven't found any ember cli examples for this yet but check out this tutorial from LinkedIn: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial

Comment: @Mikeumus The problem I had with this was that I wasn't sure how to manually include the linkedin sdk in an ember cli project. I tried using require.js (packaged with ember cli) to manually include the sdk but wasn't sure how to pass in the required arguments or how to make api calls from within the scope of ember controllers and routes